Error: EagerLoadingError [SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: Client is not associated to Job
I'm trying to create database associations using Sequelize, but when I try test them I get an error saying that there are no associations. I've tried moving the order of the models and other code, but no luck. All other answers I have looked at haven't given a clear answer for me. Any help would be appreciated.
initDb.ts
import sequelize from "./database/models/db";
import User from './database/models/User';
import Profile from './database/models/Profile';
import Client from './database/models/Client';
import Job from './database/models/Job';
import Sample from './database/models/Sample';
import SamplePhoto from './database/models/SamplePhoto';
import Test from './database/models/Test';

const models = {
    User,
    Profile,
    Client,
    Job,
    Sample,
    SamplePhoto,
    Test,
};

// synchronize all models to database.
const syncDatabase = async () => {
    try {
        await sequelize.sync({ force: true });

        // initialize model associations
        Object.values(models).forEach(model => model.associate && model.associate(models));

        console.log('Database synchronized successfully');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error synchronizing database:', error);
    };
};

syncDatabase();

export default syncDatabase;

db.ts
// create sequelize instance to establish connection to database
const sequelize = new Sequelize(database, username, password, {
    host: host,
    dialect: 'postgres',
});

// test whether database connection is successful
const testDatabaseConnection = async () => {
    try {
        await sequelize.authenticate();
        console.log('Database connection is successful');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the database. ', error);
    }
};

testDatabaseConnection();

export default sequelize;

Client model
import { Model, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
import sequelize from './db';    // import database instance from database.ts
import { ModelsInterface, ClientAttributes } from '../types/models-interface';

// In Typescript '!' means the attribute must be assigned a value and '?' means it is optional
class Client extends Model<ClientAttributes> implements ClientAttributes {
    id!: number;
    name!: string;
    email!: string;
    phoneNumber?: string;
    addressLine?: string;
    suburb?: string;
    state?: string;
    postcode?: string;
    fullAddress?: string;    // virtual field
    purchaseOrderNumber?: string;

    static associate(models: ModelsInterface) {
        Client.hasMany(models.Job, { foreignKey: "clientId" });    // establish hasMany relationship with Job model
    }
};

Client.init({
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
        validate: {
            isEmail: true,
        },
    },
    phoneNumber: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    addressLine: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    suburb: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    state: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    postcode: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    fullAddress: {
        type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
        get() {
            if (!this.addressLine || !this.suburb || !this.state || !this.postcode) {
                return "";
            }
            return `${this.addressLine}, ${this.suburb} ${this.state} ${this.postcode}`;
        },
        set(value: string) {
            throw new Error("Do not try to set the 'fullAddress' value");
        }
    },
    purchaseOrderNumber: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
        unique: true,
    },
}, {
    sequelize,    // Pass the sequelized instance. It tells which database instance to use for that model.
    modelName: 'Client',
    tableName: 'clients',
    timestamps: true,
});

export default Client;

Job model
import { Model, DataTypes } from "sequelize";
import { ModelsInterface, JobAttributes } from "../types/models-interface";
import sequelize from "./db";
import Client from "./Client";

class Job extends Model<JobAttributes> implements JobAttributes {
    id!: number;
    clientId!: number;
    jobNumber!: string;
    comments?: string;
    dueDate!: Date;
    completed?: boolean;

    static associate(models: ModelsInterface) {
        Job.belongsTo(models.Client, { foreignKey: "clientId", constraints: false });
        Job.hasMany(models.Sample, { foreignKey: "jobNumber" });
    };

    // create a new job number based on the most recent job number
    static async createJobNumber(): Promise<string> {
        // get most recent job number
        const latestJobNumber = await Job.findOne({
            order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
        });

        if (latestJobNumber) {
            // split jobNumber into year and number
            const [year, number] = latestJobNumber.jobNumber.split("-");
            const newNumber = parseInt(number, 10) + 1;  // using 10 base to ensure unexpected behavior e.g. leading zeroes.
            return `${year}-JOB-${newNumber}`;
        } else {
            const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear().toString();
            return `${currentYear}-JOB-1`;
        };
    };
};

Job.init({
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
    },
    clientId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
            model: Client,
            key: "id"
        },
    },
    jobNumber: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
    },
    comments: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
    },
    dueDate: {
        type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
        validate: {
            isDate: true,
        },
    },
    completed: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false,
    }
}, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: "Job",
    tableName: "jobs",
    timestamps: true
});

export default Job;

Dependencies

  "dependencies": {
    "sequelize": "^6.37.3",
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.6.2",
  },

Test
import sequelize from "./database/models/db";
import Client from "./database/models/Client";
import Job from "./database/models/Job";

async function testAssociations() {
    // Create a client
    const client = await Client.create({
        name: 'Test Client',
        email: 'client@example.com',
    });

    // Create a job associated with the client
    const job = await Job.create({
        jobNumber: '2024-JOB-01',
        clientId: client.id,
        comments: 'This is a comment',
        dueDate: new Date,
    });

    // Fetch the job along with its client
    const fetchedJob = await Job.findOne({
        where: { id: job.id },
        include: Client,
    });

    console.log('Fetched Job:', fetchedJob);
    console.log('Associated Client:', fetchedJob?.clientId);
}

// Initialize Sequelize and run the test
(async () => {
    try {
        await sequelize.authenticate();
        console.log('Database connection established.');
        await testAssociations();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    } finally {
        await sequelize.close();
    }
})();


Please add the lines of code before const fetchedJob where you import the model

Hi @Anatoly, I’ve added the rest of the code for my test. I’ve seen your answers to similar questions, but I’m still having trouble resolving my issue. Looking forward to your reply. Thanks!

Did you try to import models from initDb.ts to use in test module? So that way you use direct imports from model modules only in initDb.ts
